# How to order the months chronologically in plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

[image]

As everyone can see on the X-axis, the order of months are random however I want to order the months chronologically from January to December. Thank you for the answers!!

```
**#Counting the number of guests in both resort and city hotels**

Resort_Guests_Monhtly = Rh.groupby("arrival_date_month")["hotel"].count()
City_Guests_Monthly = Ch.groupby("arrival_date_month")["hotel"].count()

Resort_Guests_data = pd.DataFrame({"month":list(Resort_Guests_Monhtly.index), 
                               "hotel":"Resort hotel",
                               "guests":list(Resort_Guests_Monhtly.values)})

City_Guests_data = pd.DataFrame({"month":list(City_Guests_Monthly.index), 
                               "hotel":"City Hotel",
                               "guests":list(City_Guests_Monthly.values)}) function

**#Concenate the city and resort hotel data** 

all_guests_data =pd.concat([Resort_Guests_data,City_Guests_data],ignore_index=True)

**#Trying to order the months but didn't work** 

ordered_months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
      "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
all_guests_data['month'] = pd.Categorical(all_guests_data['month'], categories=ordered_months, ordered=True)


 **#Visulization**

fig = px.line(all_guests_data, x="month" , y="guests",title="Average number of hotel guests per month", color='hotel')
fig.show()
```

Comment: "on the X-axis, the order of months are random" -- not random but alphabetically.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel actually you are right, are there any way to change that to chronological order?

Comment: Use 1-12 as the xaxis *values*, and mask that with Jan-Dec as xaxis *labels*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if we go around to solve the x-axis order, we can treat the matter as sorting the data in DataFrame `all_guests_data` on the column `month` according to the `ordered_months` list.

Therefore, we add the following two lines before `**#Visulization**`

```
all_guests_data['to_sort']=all_guests_data['month'].apply(lambda x:ordered_months.index(x))
all_guests_data = all_guests_data.sort_values('to_sort')
```

*Clarification Example*

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

# initializing data with monthes that are not in the correct order with acompanied with the given values
data={'month':["May", "June","July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December","January", "February", "March", "April"],
      'guests':[50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,10,20,30,40]}
all_guests_data = pd.DataFrame(data)

ordered_months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
      "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

# sorting data accoring to ordered_months
all_guests_data['to_sort']=all_guests_data['month'].apply(lambda x:ordered_months.index(x))
all_guests_data = all_guests_data.sort_values('to_sort')

# Visulization
fig = px.line(all_guests_data, x="month" , y="guests" )
fig.write_html('first_figure.html', auto_open=True)
```

Comment: @Soleil-MathieuPrévot: Why do you believe this doesn't provide an answer to the question? I'm not sure if it's a _correct_ answer, but that's what voting is for.